# How to create a categorized progress bar

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization, visualization

I am trying to create a status bar that is similar to something we see currently in a different reporting tool (see attached image). I want to use matplotlib to generate this as an image, that way it could be used in several different places and reports.

I cannot find a good guide that can walk me through how to do this using Matplotlib in particular.  I am passing in the data as:

```
results = {'pass': 5, 'fail':18, 'na': 10, 'todo': 187, 'blocked': 12, 'aborted': 10}
```

I would like it to look similar to this chart:

[image: Bar Chart]

Can anyone guide me to the right resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took the code of the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/horizontal_barchart_distribution.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-horizontal-barchart-distribution-py) and apply some changes in order to apply it to your case.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

results = {'Pass': 5, 'Fail':18, 'Na': 10, 'Todo': 187, 'Blocked': 12, 'Aborted': 10}

category_names = [f'{value} {category.upper()}' for category, value in results.items()]

results = {'1': list(results.values())}

labels = list(results.keys())
data = np.array(list(results.values()))
data_cum = data.cumsum(axis = 1)
category_colors = plt.get_cmap('RdYlGn')(np.linspace(0.15, 0.85, data.shape[1]))

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10, 2))
ax = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.4, 0.8, 0.4])

ax.axis('off')

for i, (colname, color) in enumerate(zip(category_names, category_colors)):
    widths = data[:, i]
    starts = data_cum[:, i] - widths
    ax.barh(labels, widths, left = starts, height = 0.5, label = colname, color = color)

ax.legend(ncol = len(category_names), bbox_to_anchor = (0, 0), loc = 'upper left', fontsize = 10, frameon = False)

plt.show()
```

[image]

If you want to format the legend too, you can replace `ax.legend` line above with (you have to import `transforms` with `from matplotlib import transforms`):

```
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()

for label, color, position in zip(labels, category_colors, np.linspace(0, 220, len(labels))):
    text = plt.text(position, -0.5, label.split()[0] + ' ', color = color, size = 15, horizontalalignment = 'right')
    text.draw(fig.canvas.get_renderer())
    ex = text.get_window_extent()
    transforms.offset_copy(text._transform, y = ex.height, units = 'dots')
    text = plt.text(position + 2, -0.5, label.split()[1], color = 'black', size = 10, horizontalalignment = 'left')
    text.draw(fig.canvas.get_renderer())
    ex = text.get_window_extent()
    transforms.offset_copy(text._transform, y = ex.height, units = 'dots')
```

[image]

In this case you have to optimize:

- figure size (`figsize = (10, 2)`)
- total length of the legend (`np.linspace(0, 220, len(labels))`)
- space between text (`position + 2`)
- text size (`size = 15`)

based on your needs.

Comment: Thank you for your help on this! It works wonderfully!  The only remaining thing for me to figure out is how to specify label colors. :)

Comment: In the case above, colors are picked from `category_colors` which takes color from the colormap `plt.get_cmap('RdYlGn')`